# How to get min value of an attribute from array of arrays

Tags: reactjs

From the below array, I need to get the element with the lowest "cost" value from attributes.
"attributes" is another array in each element.

So it should give me the entry with productId - 1, as it has the least cost - 100.
How can we do this in React/javascript? Please help.

```
[
{
    "productId": 1,
    "attributes": [
        {
            "id": 101,
            "name": "quantity",
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "id": 102,
            "name": "description",
            "value": "product 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 103,
            "name": "cost",
            "value": 100
        }
    ]
},
{
    "productId": 2,
    "attributes": [
        {
            "id": 101,
            "name": "quantity",
            "value": 5
        },
        {
            "id": 102,
            "name": "description",
            "value": "product 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 103,
            "name": "cost",
            "value": 150
        }
    ]
},
{
    "productId": 3,
    "attributes": [
        {
            "id": 101,
            "name": "quantity",
            "value": 20
        },
        {
            "id": 102,
            "name": "description",
            "value": "product 3"
        },
        {
            "id": 103,
            "name": "cost",
            "value": 200
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Answer (score 2):

My idea is using sort array by asc and get first one:

```
let min = arr.sort((a, b) => a.attributes.find(e => e.name === "cost")["value"] - b.attributes.find(e => e.name === "cost")["value"])[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

This method should do it:

```
yourArray.reduce(
  (acc, cur) => {
    let cost = cur.attributes.filter((a) => a.name == "cost")[0].value;
    if (cost < acc.cheapestCost) acc.cheapestProduct = cur;
    return acc;
  },
  { cheapestProduct: {}, cheapestCost: 1000000 }
).cheapestProduct;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const lowest = givenArray.reduce((prev, next) => {
  return (prev.attributes[2].value < next.attributes[2].value) ? prev : next
})
```